# Pandas: Conditional filtering based on the last row of each dataframe within another datarame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` as follows

```
Date          Group   Value   Duration
2018-01-01      A      20       30
2018-02-01      A      10       60
2018-03-01      A      25       88    <-----Last row for Group A
2018-01-01      B      15      180
2018-02-01      B      30      210
2018-03-01      B      25      238    <-----Last row of Group B
```

I want to drop the `Group` A because it hax max duration less than 90. Or in other words, considering the last row of each `Group`, if the `Duration` value is less than 90, we omit that group. So my resultant data frame should look like

```
    Date       Group   Value   Duration
 2018-01-01      B      15      180
 2018-02-01      B      30      210
 2018-03-01      B      25      240
```

To achieve this, my approach is as follows:

```
df_f = []
for k,v in df.groupby(['Group']):
    v_f = v[max(v['Duration'])>=90]
    df_f.append(v_f)
```

The above code snippet is throwing an error as `KeyError: False`

Am I missing out anything here?

Comment: @jezrael: Yes filter operation is tad slow, but given the size of the actual data, I think it would not impact that much.

Comment: OK, it is slow in small DataFrame, 1k rows, but it is up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test if maximal value per groups is hogher of equal like `90` in [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.groupby('Group')['Duration'].transform('max') >= 90]
#alternative
#df = df[df.groupby('Group')['Duration'].transform('max').ge(90)]
print (df)
         Date Group  Value  Duration
3  2018-01-01     B     15       180
4  2018-02-01     B     30       210
5  2018-03-01     B     25       238
```

EDIT: I suggest dont use `filter` for filtration per groups, because slow:

```
#1k rows
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': np.random.randint(100, size=N),
                   'Duration':np.random.randint(200,size=N)})

#print (df)

In [24]: %timeit df.groupby('Group').filter(lambda x: x.Duration.max()>=90)
39.8 ms ± 1.15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [25]: %timeit df[df.groupby('Group')['Duration'].transform('max') >= 90]
3.12 ms ± 37.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

```
#100k rows
np.random.seed(123)
N = 100000
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': np.random.randint(1000, size=N),
                   'Duration':np.random.randint(200,size=N)})

#print (df)


In [29]: %timeit df[df.groupby('Group')['Duration'].transform('max') >= 90]
11.8 ms ± 153 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [30]: %timeit df.groupby('Group').filter(lambda x: x.Duration.max()>=90)
394 ms ± 8.92 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: @jazrel: How can I filter based on Date column? That is based on the `last date in the df if the Duration >=90, then 1 else 0.`

Comment: @pythondumb - added solution to your new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use filter.

```
df.groupby('Group').filter(lambda x: x.Duration.max()>=90)

    Date        Group   Value   Duration
3   2018-01-01  B       15      180
4   2018-02-01  B       30      210
5   2018-03-01  B       25      238
```