# Pandas: Filter or Groupby then transform to select the last row

Tags: python, pandas

This post has a reference to one of [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61862779/pandas-conditional-filtering-based-on-the-last-row-of-each-dataframe-within-ano) in SO.

Just to reiterate, I have a dataframe `df` as

```
   Date        Group   Value   Duration
 2018-01-01      A      20       30
 2018-02-01      A      10       60
 2018-03-01      A      25       88    <-----Last row for Group A
 2018-01-01      B      15      180
 2018-02-01      B      30      210
 2018-03-01      B      25      238    <-----Last row of Group B
```

Considering the last row of each Group, if the Duration value is less than 90, we omit that group. So my resultant data frame `df_final` should look like

```
    Date       Group   Value   Duration
 2018-01-01      B      15      180
 2018-02-01      B      30      210
 2018-03-01      B      25      240
```

There are two ways we approach to this problem.

First is `filter` method:

```
df.groupby('Group').filter(lambda x: x.Duration.max()>=90)
```

Second is `groupby.transform` method:

```
df = df[df.groupby('Group')['Duration'].transform('last') >= 90]
```

But I want to filter this by the `Date` column and NOT by `Duration`. I am getting the correct result by the following code:

```
df_interim = df.loc[(df['Date']=='2019-03-01')&(df['Duration'] >=90)]
df_final = df.merge(df_interim[['Group','Date']],on='Group',how='right').reset_index()
```

In the above code, I have hard coded the `Date`.

My question is : How can I dynamically select the last date in the data frame? And then perform the `filter` or `groupby.transform` on `Group`?

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

We can select the last date by use `transform` as well

```
lastd=df.groupby('Date')['Duration'].transform('max') 
df_interim = df.loc[(df['Date']==lastd)&(df['Duration'] >=90)]
```

Comment: This is giving me `zero` length

Answer (score 0):

I think you need first filter for maximum index by `Date` by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html), then select rows by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for all columns:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df1 = df.loc[df.groupby('Group')['Date'].idxmax()]
print (df1)
        Date Group  Value  Duration
2 2018-03-01     A     25        88
5 2018-03-01     B     25       238
```

Then filter by `Duration` only rows with maximal `Date`:

```
g = df1.loc[df1['Duration'] >= 90, 'Group']
print (g)
        Date Group  Value  Duration
3 2018-01-01     B     15       180
4 2018-02-01     B     30       210
5 2018-03-01     B     25       238
```

And last filter original `Group` column by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['Group'].isin(g)]
print (df)
        Date Group  Value  Duration
3 2018-01-01     B     15       180
4 2018-02-01     B     30       210
5 2018-03-01     B     25       238
```